# Tornado Framework - how to use Handlersrequest to call an asynchronous function

Tags: python, tornado

This is a Python code for a Tornado web application. The code defines two classes, BaseHandler and MainHandlerIndex, both of which inherit from the Tornado web library's RequestHandler. The BaseHandler class has a method, "get_username_id_get_data", which returns the username ID obtained from a "get_data" module. The MainHandlerIndex class has a "get" method decorated with the "@decoradores.authenticated" and "@gen.coroutine" decorators, which handles incoming GET requests. This method retrieves the username cookie, obtains the username ID using the "get_username_id_get_data" method, and then renders an HTML template "index/index.html" with the title, items, username, and version as variables.

```
import tornado.web
from tornado import gen
from functools import wraps
import modulos.decoradores as decoradores
import modulos.get_data as get_data
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

import tracemalloc; tracemalloc.start()


class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    async def get_username_id_get_data(self):
        print("soy basehandler y estoy siendo ejecutado....")
        username_id = await get_data.primero_redis_segundo_query("user", "('username', '=', 'test')", 'x')

        print("get_username_id_get_data: ", username_id)
        return username_id


class MainHandlerIndex(BaseHandler):
  
    @decoradores.authenticated
    @gen.coroutine
    async def get(self):
        print("Iniciando MainHandlerIndex metodo: GET")
        username_cookie_pre = self.get_secure_cookie("user")
        username_cookie = username_cookie_pre.decode()
        #username_cookie = 'test'
        username_id = await self.get_username_id_get_data()
        version = self.application.settings['valores_entorno']['version']
        print("###########################################################################")
        print("00_username_cookie------------>",username_cookie )
        print("11_username_id------------>",username_id )
        print("22_version------------>",version )
        print("###########################################################################")

        items_test = ["Item 1_index", "Item 2_index", "Item 3_index"]
        #items_test = []
        self.render("index/index.html", title="test", items=items_test, username=str(username_cookie).strip("\""), version=version)
```

This is the contents of the file index.py:

```
import asyncio
import os
import tornado.web

#----------------------------#
#  Definir entorno           #
#----------------------------#

from config import Settings, PreProductionSettings, ProductionSettings
import tornado.options
tornado.options.parse_config_file('config.py')
valores_entorno = PreProductionSettings()
#print(tornado.options.options.version)


#----------------------------#
#   Handlers from modules    #
#----------------------------#

from blueprints.test.handlers import MainHandlerTest    #TEST <-- Borrar....from blueprints.index.handlers import MainHandlerIndex  #Index
from blueprints.rid_propios.ri_handlers import MainHandlerRid_Propio_Index  #Remote_id_propios
from blueprints.login.login_handlers import MainHandlerLogin, LogoutHandler, RegisterHandler, ConfirmeHandler
from blueprints.index.handlers import MainHandlerIndex


#----------------------------#
#   Módulos del proyecto     #
#----------------------------#
import modulos.gestiondb as gestiondb
import modulos.redis_stack as redisstack
import modulos.tablas  as Tablas


from aiopg.sa import create_engine


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
print("BASE_DIR: ", BASE_DIR)


engine = create_engine(
        user=tornado.options.options.user,
        database=tornado.options.options.database,
        host=tornado.options.options.host, 
        password=tornado.options.options.password,
        )


def make_app():

    settings = {
        "template_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"), #/home/developer/xrig_torado/web/web/blueprints/base/templates
        "blueprints_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "web/blueprints"), #/home/developer/xrig_torado/web/web/blueprints
        "static_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),      #/home/developer/xrig_torado/web/static
        "cookie_secret": tornado.options.options.cookie_secret,
        "login_url": "/login",
        "xsrf_cookies": True,
        "valores_entorno": tornado.options.options
    }

    handlers = (
    (r'/', MainHandlerIndex),
    (r'/login', MainHandlerLogin),
    (r'/logout', LogoutHandler),
    (r'/register', RegisterHandler),
    (r'/confirmar', ConfirmeHandler),
    (r'/test', MainHandlerTest),
    (r'/rid_propios_index', MainHandlerRid_Propio_Index)
    )


    return tornado.web.Application(
        handlers,
        debug = True,
        autoreload = True,
        **settings,
        #db = db
        db_engine = engine,
    )

    

async def main():
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(tornado.options.options.puerto_xrig)
    #await asyncio.Event().wait()
    await asyncio.Event().wait()
    print(f' Server is listening on localhost on port {tornado.options.options.puerto_xrig}')


    #Comprobando que existen la tablas del proyecto:
    db_dsn = tornado.options.options.dsn
    #lista_tablas = [gestiondb.tbl_benchmark, gestiondb.alpha, gestiondb.user,   ]
    lista_tablas = [Tablas.tbl_benchmark, Tablas.alpha, Tablas.user, Tablas.rid, Tablas.rid_propio  ]
    await gestiondb.rutina_alta_db_proyecto(db_dsn, lista_tablas)

    #Comprobaciones Redis Stack.
    await redisstack.lista_tablas_para_volcar_en_redis()

    shutdown_event = asyncio.Event()
    await shutdown_event.wait()
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The extension starts correctly, does the login process and once the authenticated user is when I make a redirect to the root path / (this is where I can not operate a code that can call asynchronous functions). I have tried to follow several examples and there is no way the error is always:

http://http://192.168.196.49:8888/  (depués del proceso login)

```
[I 230205 19:48:57 web:2271] 200 GET / (192.168.196.4) 14.50ms
/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py:80: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'MainHandlerIndex.get' was never awaited
  self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
Object allocated at (most recent call last):
  File "/home/developer/xrig_torado/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", lineno 216
    result = ctx_run(func, *args, **kwargs)
[W 230205 19:48:57 web:2271] 404 GET /favicon.ico (192.168.196.4) 7.46ms
```

I do NOT find enough documentation that explains an architecture to do this kind of thing. The intention is in the requestHandler in the GET or POST method to develop code and be able to call asynchronous functions.

Comment: Try and reduce your code to a minimal reproduction, e.g. one end point that does something simple.

Comment: Of course it is good advice, it is the best practice to start with something very simple and increase the complexity. But I've already tried it, I may have a problem of concept. in the GET method I add async in the function to use await this is how they commit in the examples and documentation and that's when it starts to fail.

Comment: Another tip: shorter lines, so scrolling horizontally here is not required, if you wrap a long command with `(` brackets `)` then you can line break as many times as you want between them

Comment: I've only used flask and fastapi libraries for this in Python, so I can't help. This is actually the first I've heard of tornado.

Comment: The problem I have with Flask as it is a large application some large process is blocking  CPU and does not do processes concurrently. When it begins to be used by several users and launch tasks, the web stops responding. I'm even using Celery to manage asynchronous tasks but the problem is in Flask. In tornado I was reading that it has the technology none blocking I/O.

Comment: fastapi supports this too, I do know how they compare.

Comment: thks will see this fastapi.